# Finiteness in the Proof of Lemma on Absolute Continuity of Measures.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

To prove that absolute continuity implies $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion, it is said that finiteness is required. The proof involves construction of sequences of measurable sets, where their upper bound and lower bound are implied by the construction itself. I don’t really see explicitly where the proof utilises finiteness. I do know that the finiteness is required due to a counterexample given in the text.

Edit: The proof that I mentioned is the one in the link titled Step 1.
https://www.math3ma.com/blog/absolute-continuity-part-two

Comment: There is more that one way to prove that the absolute continuity implies $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @Ramiro added link. Initially I thought the proof is quite similar across the texts, so I didn’t write down the details.

Comment: Finite measures are continuous from above but this fails for infinite measures. Ex. $\lambda (n,\infty)$ does not tend to $0$ even though $(n,\infty)$ decreases to empty set.

Comment: Regarding the proof in the link you posted.

Note that $\{F_k\}_k$ is a sequence of measurable sets such that $F_1 \supseteq F_2 \supseteq F_3 \supseteq \cdots$ , and $\mu(F_1)<+\infty$. So we can use the continuity from above for $\mu$ and the sequence $\{F_k\}_k$. 

But, for $\nu$, we only know that $\nu(F_k) \geq \varepsilon$, for all $k$. So without the condition that $\nu$ is finite, we cannot use the continuity from above for $\nu$ and the sequence $\{F_k\}_k$.